# how to do multiple if statemnts in php based on a criteria

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database named `hrRecords` and a table named employee in that table. It has a field named `contract_end`. In that field, I have the contract info of the employee specifically the duration of said contract (`datetime`).

What I want to achieve is to check that info to see when the contract is going to come to an end and if it is display a message saying so.

I am very new to php and I tried something but I am totally lost I was wondering if I could get some guidance of some sort thank you for your support:

```
<?php
$employee1= mysql_real_escape($_GET["employee1"]);
$DataBase = "hrRecords"; 
mysql_connect("server","username", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($DataBase) or die(mysql_error());
$query = SELECT contract_end From hrRecords

// current date being compared
if(contract_end== date(Y-m-d) {
        echo "something"
    }
else {
        echo " employe name , Your contract will expire in x amount of days "
    }

/* This is the point where everything becomes fuzzy because im thinking there has to be some other way to do this for all the employees */
```

Comment: There are a number of syntax errors in your example code. Is this the actual code you are running? For example the value of `$query` needs to be a quoted string, and you have a stray dot in front of the `date` command. Also your first `echo` is missing the closing quote of its string.

Comment: @ Dan Lowe its not actually implemented as yet but from what i have read about php i constructed this small snippet

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Too many errors here to answer.

Answer (score 0):

fist stop using mysql it has been depreciated
use either mysqli or pdo. I will show you how to do it with mysqli

```
<?php
$employee1= mysql_real_escape($_GET["employee1"]); // i am not sure why you are doing this since you are not using this any where
$DataBase = "hrRecords";
$ServerName = "server";
$UserName = "username";
$Password = "password"; 
$mysqli = new mysqli($ServerName, $UserName, $Password,$DataBase);
// Check connection
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
// since i don't know all of colum names i am making them up
$stmt= $mysqli->prepare("SELECT contract_end employe_name From hrRecords");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($contract_end, $employe_name)
while($stmt->fetch()) { // this will go thorough all of the records
// current date being compared
if($contract_end== date(Y-m-d) { 
    echo "something"
} else {
// you need some more code here to find x
    echo " $employe name , Your contract will expire in x amount of days "
}
}
```

i don't know if this will help you at all.  you did not have enough info for a better answer